# Creating a function in python and assigning integers

Tags: python

I'm doing exercise 20 in LPTHW and I'm working my wall through the study drill.I have a question regarding one line of code. For your reference, I print out the code:

```
from sys import argv

script, input_file = argv

def print_all(f):
    print(f.read())

def rewind(f):
    f.seek(0)

def print_a_line(line_count, f):
    print(line_count, f.readline())

current_file = open(input_file)

print("First let's print the whole file:\n")

print_all(current_file)

print("Now let's rewind, kind of like a tape.")

rewind(current_file)

print("Let's print three lines:")

current_line = 1
print_a_line(current_line, current_file)

current_line = current_line + 1
print_a_line(current_line, current_file)

current_line = current_line + 1
print_a_line(current_line, current_file)
```

My issue is, how does the below function, know to reference `current_line` as the integer?

```
def print_a_line(line_count, f): 
    print(line_count, f.readline())
```

Really struggling here...sorry if it is a silly question!

Comment: `current_line` is passed to `print_a_line` as an argument.

Comment: BTW, when you call `print_a_line`, you can pass it any number, it's not _really_ the line count. In fact, you could pass it anything and it'll get printed.

Comment: FWIW, the SO Python Chat room regulars [do not recommend LPTHW](http://sopython.com/wiki/LPTHW_Complaints). If it's working for you, that's great, but please be aware that there are several problems with this book.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I intend to finish this book then move onto 'Automate the Boring Stuff'. Out of curiosity can you let me know the several problems you identified?

Comment: @JimmyK the problems with that book are listed in the link in PM 2Ring's comment, same as this - https://sopython.com/wiki/LPTHW_Complaints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you make a function call of:

```
print_a_line(current_line, current_file)
```

you are passing the values of `current_line` and `current_file` to the `print_a_line` function to make the call, so the value of `current_line` gets assigned as an argument to the parameter `line_count`, and the value of `current_file` gets assigned as an argument to the parameter `f` inside the `print_a_line` function, so that they can be referenced as local variables there.

Comment: Thanks so much! Really simple, don't know why I skimmed over this logic. Very helpful comment